# get GPS coordinates from Time Zone or ip address

Tags: c, geolocation

I am trying to make a small application (in **C/C++**) which can tell the user his gps coordinates with out having an actual gps device. I am planning to do this by using current time zone or ip address (or both, may be). Does any one know of any `C` library that could be of help?

I know how to find time zone and ip address, but I am not aware of any library that can give gps coordinates using them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time Zone won't give you very much accuracy, a single time zone may be several hundred kilometers wide and about 2000 kilometers tall! GeoIp services may help.

Comment: Yes, I understand that accuracy with time zone would be very bad. The "GeoIp" service you told about, is there any thing similar for 'C/C++'. I don't want to do screen scraping from some web page...

Comment: There will be web services available to provide geographic locations in XML or JSON etc. These will be fairly accurate (as good as you'll get without GPS or Cell Tower Triangulation), but may not be free...

Answer (score 1):

[geoip library](http://www.maxmind.com/app/c) might be what you are looking for. But the [database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) is quite big (30MB). You can use smaller, [country database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry), but it doesn't contain geographic coordinates.